# How to change arrow rotation when select box is active using CSS

Tags: html, css

Basically, i'm creating a custom select box when i finished the design part using css and when i wanted to add the "before" and "active" options so that the "arrow" and "menu" changes when the select box is active, I had some problems, when i add "active" to the class name in the browser the arrow is supposed to rotate but nothing happens instead.
**HTML**

```
<div class="custom_select_box_1_index">

            <ul id="DefaultCategoryIndex"class="default_option_category_index">
              <li>
                <div class="option_allcategories">
                    <p>All Categories</p>
                    <i id="ArrowCategoryIndex" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="OptionsCategoryIndex" class="select_option_category_index">
              <li>
                <div id="CategoryObjects" class="option objects">
                  <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-cube"></i></div>
                    <p class="category_text">Objects</p>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li>
                <div id="CategoryVehicules" class="option vehicules">
                  <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-car"></i></div>
                    <p class="category_text">Vehicules</p>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li>
                <div id="CategoryTechnology" class="option technology">
                  <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-mobile"></i></div>
                    <p class="category_text">Technology</p>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li>
                <div id="CategoryBooks" class="option books">
                  <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-book"></i></div>
                    <p class="category_text">Books</p>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li>
                <div id="CategoryGaming" class="option gaming">
                  <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-gamepad"></i></div>
                    <p class="category_text">Gaming</p>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li>
                <div id="CategoryOther" class="option other">
                  <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
                    <p class="category_text">Other...</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .custom_select_box_1_index{
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 19px;
      color: var(--second-black);
      box-sizing: content-box;
      width: 250px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    .custom_select_box_1_index > ul li{
      list-style: none;
      }
    
    .custom_select_box_1_index .default_option_category_index:before{
      content: "";
      padding-top: 1px;
      padding-bottom: 1px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: var(--white);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      color: var(--black);
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 170px;
      margin-top: -39px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .custom_select_box_1_index .select_option_category_index{
      background-color: var(--white);
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      z-index: 1;
      display: none
    }
    
    .select_option_category_index li{
      position: relative;
      margin-left: -38px;
      background-color: var(--white);
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 230px;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .custom_select_box_1_index .select_option_category_index li:hover{
      background: var(--grey);
    }
    
    .category_text{
      position: relative;
      left: 30px;
    }
    
    .custom_select_box_1_index .option{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .icon{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    #icon{
      color: var(--black);
    }
    
    .custom_select_box_1_index:active .select_option_category_index{
      display: block;
    }
    
    .custom_select_box_1_index:active .default_option_category_index:before{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

I want the arrow to rotate back to 0deg when the select bar is active **(without using JavaScript)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the CSS adjacent sibling selector [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```css
.custom_select_box_1_index {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: var(--second-black);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

.custom_select_box_1_index>ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.custom_select_box_1_index .default_option_category_index:before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--white);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: var(--black);
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: -39px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom_select_box_1_index .select_option_category_index {
  background-color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none
}

.select_option_category_index li {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -38px;
  background-color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom_select_box_1_index .select_option_category_index li:hover {
  background: var(--grey);
}

.category_text {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}

.custom_select_box_1_index .option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#icon {
  color: var(--black);
}

.custom_select_box_1_index:active .select_option_category_index {
  display: block;
}

.custom_select_box_1_index:active .default_option_category_index:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.option_allcategories p:active+.fa-chevron-up {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="custom_select_box_1_index">

  <ul id="DefaultCategoryIndex" class="default_option_category_index">
    <li>
      <div class="option_allcategories">
        <p>All Categories</p>
        <i id="ArrowCategoryIndex" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="OptionsCategoryIndex" class="select_option_category_index">
    <li>
      <div id="CategoryObjects" class="option objects">
        <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-cube"></i></div>
        <p class="category_text">Objects</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div id="CategoryVehicules" class="option vehicules">
        <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-car"></i></div>
        <p class="category_text">Vehicules</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div id="CategoryTechnology" class="option technology">
        <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-mobile"></i></div>
        <p class="category_text">Technology</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div id="CategoryBooks" class="option books">
        <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-book"></i></div>
        <p class="category_text">Books</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div id="CategoryGaming" class="option gaming">
        <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-gamepad"></i></div>
        <p class="category_text">Gaming</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div id="CategoryOther" class="option other">
        <div class="icon"><i id="icon" class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
        <p class="category_text">Other...</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How do i make the menu keep showing and not disappearing right after clicking?

Comment: @MvTakuXx You need JavaScript for that.